# Does convergence in law imply convergence in convex distance?

Tags: pr.probability

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^m$, the convex distance $d_c$ is defined as

$$d_c(X,Y) = \sup_{h} \lvert \operatorname{E}(h(X)) - \operatorname{E}(h(Y)) \rvert,$$

where the supremum is taken over all indicator functions of measurable convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

For $m=1$, it is easy to see that $d_c$ coincides with the Kolmogorov distance whenever $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, i.e. we have that $d_c(X,Y)= \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \lvert F_X(x) -F_Y(x) \rvert$, where $F_X$ and $F_Y$ denote the cumulative distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

In particular, if $m=1$, we have that if a sequence $(X_n)$ of continuous real-valued random variables converges to another continuous random variable $Y$ in distribution, then $d_c(X_n,Y) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Does this implication continue to hold if $m \geq 2$?

I could neither find a reference, nor a proof of this myself.

**EDIT**

If continuity of the random variables is defined as having non-atomic distributions, the implication is false (see the counterexample by Iosif Pinelis below).

If continuity is defined as having CDFs which are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, the question is still open.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, even for $m=1$.  Convergence in Kolmogorov distance is stronger than convergence in distribution, not weaker.  Take for instance deterministic $X_n = 1/n$ and $Y=0$.  And they don't converge in convex distance either, by taking $h = 1_{\{0\}}$ or $1_{[-1,0]}$.  Is there a mistake, or assumptions missing?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thany you much for your comment, I somehow forgot to add the crucial assumption that the random variables are continuous.

Comment: So, in the second-to-last paragraph, you want $Y$ to be continuous as well as $X_n$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, corrected this as well, now the question should be well-posed.

Comment: How do you define a continuous random vector in $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis like in $\mathbb{R}$: its cumulative distribution function is continuous. Are there other (non-equivalent) ways to define continuity?

Comment: The other way is absolute continuity with respect to the Lebesgue measure. As illustrated by Iosif's answer, this is not equivalent.

Comment: @r_faszanatas: Well, there are many ways, but this one is particularly flawed: according to it, the uniform distribution on an interval is continuous if and only if the interval is neither horizontal nor vertical, which seems rather artificial.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki this is something I should know by heart, thanks a lot for bringing it up in a friendly way. I completely agree that my definition is not a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. For instance, let $Y$ be uniformly distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^m$ (not the ball, but the sphere) and, for each natural $n$, let $X_n:=(1+1/n)Y$. Then the distribution of each of the random vectors $Y,X_1,X_2,\dots$ is [non-atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures) and hence, in particular, the values of this distribution on any singleton set are $0$; also, the cumulative distribution function of this distribution is continuous.

Moreover, $X_n\to Y$ in distribution, but $d_c(X_n,Y)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this counterexample. Given the comments above: Can you add to your answer that continuity is defined the way I commented (cumulative distribution function is just continuous)? Also, it would be nice to settle the question for the better definition of absolute continuity with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @r_faszanatas : A better definition of the continuity of a random vector is that its distribution be non-atomic (which in the one-dimensional case coincides with the usual definition of the continuity of a random variable). The distributions of $X_n$ and $Y$ in the counterexample are indeed non-atomic.

Comment: As always, I learned a lot from this question, thanks again. So now the question is, if the implication holds in case at least the limiting random variable has a CDF which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @r_faszanatas : I think the answer is affirmative if $Y$ is absolutely continuous. To keep things in good order, though, I think this additional question should be posted separately.

Comment: just asked this as another question, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351870/does-convergence-in-law-to-absolutely-continuous-limit-imply-convergence-in-conv